# How to extend the time that a screenshot remains on screen on macOS Mojave?

Tags: screen-capture, preferences, mojave

After taking a screenshot. The screenshot goes to the bottom right hand corner. It disappears after 5 seconds (yes I timed it). How can I extend this time?[image]

Comment: or better still, stop it doing that at all - by heck it's annoying :/

Comment: @Tetsujin Haha. It annoyed me so much at the begging but once I got used to it, it became very helpful when upload screenshots for tutorials. Except I am too slow and it sometimes disappears before I can use the feature :L

Comment: I'm just so used to throwing them straight into photoshop to do whatever I need to do that the extra wait is just annoying. I've looked at the annotation toolkit... doesn't do it for me, prefer Ps.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ik what you mean. I use photoshop often but I like the design of annotation toolkit for tutorials.

Comment: Lol vote to close.

Comment: I wouldn't close it - 'extend or kill' are both valid options, if a 'fix' can be found

Comment: @Tetsujin Trying to find open files with activity monitor. But the application `screencapture` only comes up when I have pointer open to take screenshot. So once I take to the screenshot it disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, not a clue... deep-down underpinnings are not my strong suit at all, I'm a high-level, GUI guy ;-)

Comment: Holding your cursor over the preview keeps it from going anywhere, at least in Catalina. Not a great answer but it's something.

Comment: Same here. It was terrible in the beginning and I was looking for a way to disable them. Meanwhile they're important part of my workflow and I would like then to stay a little longer :-)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to put the screenshot on your clipboard instead, where it will remain until you replace it with something else.

> To copy a screenshot to the Clipboard, press and hold the Control key while you're taking the screenshot. You can then paste the screenshot somewhere else.

[Apple support docs](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201361)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked! The OP wants to extends the exhibited behavior described in his question, not place the screen shot on the clipboard.

Comment: Wanting to have the screenshot visible for longer is a good example of the [_XY problem_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The reason for wanting to have it visible for longer is to have more time to decide where to place the screenshot. In this case, having it save to the clipboard is a perfectly valid solution, especially since there doesn't seem to be a direct solution to what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hitting return or capture when determining the window region you want to grab, enter command-C for copy.

Then command-V wherever you want to put it.

Haven't tried this method with full screen screenshot as I never use it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I'm not sure this answers the question; do you mean prior to capturing the screenshot? If so, I was unable to replicate this behavior on my machine.

Comment: So when you highlight the area you want to capture, just press command-C. Then you can paste wherever.

This prevents the popup from ever appearing but the image remains in your clipboard

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I still can't replicate that on my machine. You can set it to go to your clipboard by default instead of the desktop, but the copy-paste doesn't work until *after* the screenshot is taken.

Comment: This is great! Use CMD+SHIFT+5 for selection

Comment: Doesn't work, not even with Cmd+Shift+5

Comment: Only thing I could do is to click on the thumbnail, that opens the pic, and then you can do Ctrl+C and paste it. Youl'll have to close it though, but it is still faster

Answer (score 3):

I know this is slightly off-topic and not quite a direct solution to your question, but this option may be of interest to you. You mentioned taking screenshots for tutorials… . I use [Take screenshot selection, upload to imgur. + more cool things](https://github.com/jomo/imgur-screenshot) almost exclusively.

The [imgur-screenshot utility](https://github.com/jomo/imgur-screenshot), straight out of the box without configuring any options, uploads the screenshot to Imgur , opens a browser window of the uploaded screenshot (for easy access if you need to manipulate the image), copies the URL of the screenshot to your clipboard, and also stores a local copy of the image.

I actually created an AppleScript application, and included.. imgur-screenshot.sh into a script libraries folder in the application bundle…

```
on imgur_screenshot()
    set imgUR to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Script Libraries:imgur-screenshot.sh"
    set imgUR to imgUR as alias
    set imgUR to POSIX path of imgUR
    set imgUR to quoted form of imgUR
    do shell script imgUR
end imgur_screenshot

imgur_screenshot()
```

From here, with enhanced dictation enabled, I selected the new AppleScript application in Finder, and simply spoke the command “Make This Speakable”, and configured the newly created dictation command… now anytime I need to take a screenshot, I simply say “Upload Screenshot” which sets the whole process in motion

[image]

Comment: Couldn't be a @wch1zpink answer without an Apple Script :) Very cool.

Answer (score 3):

While there is an option to completely disable this feature with (`defaults write com.apple.screencapture show-thumbnail -bool FALSE`) there seems to be no option to extend the screenshot preview duration.

There are several ways to workaround the problem:

#### Paste via keyboard shortcut

- Use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to capture the Screenshot instead of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
- Afters selecting the desired area, just hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
- paste anywhere you want <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

#### Paste setting target to clipboard

- Use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to open the capture mode
- open "**Options**" and set "**Save to**" to "**Clipboard**"
- Screenshots will now always be saved to the clipboard
- Note: This will now also work doing the screenshot using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

#### Use custom folder with shortcut

- Set a custom folder for your screenshot default location
- drag the folder to your toolbar, after the first vertical line
- clicking the folder in the toolbar, will give you quick access to you recent screenshots.

[image: open screenshots folder from toolbar, showing quick access to the pictures]

Answer (score 1):

To increase the timeout (to 20 seconds in this case) run this command in the Terminal.app

```
defaults write com.apple.screencaptureui "thumbnailExpiration" -float 20
```

Then run this to restart the service and pick up the new configuration

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

If some reason the last part doesn't work (it should), restart your Mac to take effect.